# Replace slice from DataFrame and put it to the end

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to take a several number of cells from a column (C) and put it to the end of it.
The size of the dataframe must be the same. Need to replace them.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([
     [0,0,0],
     [1,1,1],
     [2,2,2],
     [3,3,3],
     [4,4,4],
     [5,5,5]])

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = ['A','B','C'])

#What i want:
     #  A B C
     # [0,0,3]
     # [1,1,4]
     # [2,2,5]
     # [3,3,0]
     # [4,4,1]
     # [5,5,2]
```

Comment: What is the logic here? Is it half of the column C which has to be flipped?

Comment: No, i need to change the slice. for example the first 2, or 3

Comment: try `>>> df.C = np.roll(df.C,3)`

Comment: @DishinHGoyani this is exactly what i am looking for. Thank you. I thought about a workaround with a list, del and a new dataframe.